# How to remove characters that repeat more than twice in a row/together in a string using python?

Tags: python, regex, replace, data-cleaning, data-preprocessing

How can we reduce a string like `haaaaaaapppppyyyyyy` to `haappyy`
Such that repetition is allowed to a maximum of twice in a row for a character in a string?

including any character ( special characters also )
converting `---------------------` to `--`

Answer (score 3):

We can use a regex replacement:

```py
inp = "haaaaaaapppppyyyyyy"
output = re.sub(r'(\w)\1{2,}', r'\1\1', inp)
print(output)  # haappyy
```

The above logic matches any one character which is followed by itself two or more times.  It then replaces with just two of the character.

Comment: how can we make this work for special characters as well? converting `---------------------` to `--
`

Comment: @GargeeSuresh More generally, use: `re.sub(r'(.)\1{2,}', r'\1\1', inp)`